# Waterproof shod?

Tags: figures-of-speech

In Norwegian we have a saying, *vanntette skodd*, that directly translated to English would be *waterproof shod*. It means that there is a segregation between two subjects such that not even water passes through.

I want to use this in a society setting:

> The rich are living with the rich, and the poor with the poor. There are *waterproof shods* between the different layers of society.

Comment: Sorry, we don't use the boot analogy in English. The answers below offer some good alternatives.  But, speaking of waterproof boots: if you ever hear someone say "you're gonna need _hip waders_"  (i.e., tall fishing boots), he's probably referring to wading in _bullshit_.

Comment: This doesn't really fit your example, but you should also make note of the English idiomatic use of the word "airtight". It's generally used not to indicate a division between two groups, but one group which nothing can break the barriers of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the idea can be expressed with the saying:

***[chinese walls](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Chinese_Wall)*** which, though generally used in financial and political contexts, it may well be used  to describe the clear and impenetrable divisions among  different social classes.

> - *An insurmountable barrier*, especially to the passage of information (ODO)
> - (idiomatic, jargon) A barrier of silence and secrecy established within an organization in order to cope with confidentiality requirements. (Wiktionary)

Comment: Except a "Chinese wall" is deliberately erected to prevent information flow, notably to prevent a conflict of interests. Repurposing it to explain class divisions introduces confusion in the mind of anyone who understands its common usage.

Comment: @MarvMills -         Chinese walls is an expression used to refer  metaphorically to   a clear and impenetrable division between two or more entities. It is not used only in politics and finance as far as I know.

Comment: That is not its common usage

Comment: Sorry Marv, but would an *impermeable membrane* be more easily and readily understood in the context?

Comment: @MarvMills - no need to argue, we are just exchanging our point of view..:))

Comment: Ok then, since you ask, I believe *impermeable membrane* whilst being a little on the scientific side (which is why I offered an alternative), has the benefit of exactly describing what the OP asked for, whereas *Chinese Wall* not only does not have the meaning the OP intended, additionally introduces context that is wholly inappropriate for the OP's usage. Don't take my word for it, look up all the definitions of Chinese Wall the internet provides and examine the full context discussed.

Comment: @MarvMills - well, I clearly disagree with you on this...let's see what other users think :)

Comment: I don't think anyone else cares! ;)

Answer (score 1):

Although it may not qualify as a figure of speech, I would suggest using the term "social mobility".  The rich live with the rich, and the poor with the poor. There is a complete lack of social mobility...

Answer (score 0):

You could say "there is an [impermeable membrane](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/impermeable) between the different layers..."

> **adj.**
>
> Impossible to permeate: an impermeable membrane; an impermeable border.
>
> *www.thefreedictionary.com*

You could also use "[impenetrable](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/impenetrable?s=t) barrier"

> **adjective**
>
> 1 not penetrable; that cannot be penetrated, pierced, entered, etc.
>
> 2 
>   inaccessible to ideas, influences, etc.
>
> *www.dictionary.com*